# Core Data simple cant get what is wrong

Tags: xcode, core-data, save

I am using coredata in xcode, have used ray wanderlich tutorial but it crashes when I try to declare context - nsmanagedobjectcontext, cant figure out what the heck is wrong, please some help

I have created core data model with only one entity Datum and have created nsManagedObjectSublass files Datum.h and Datum.m

app delegate wasn't changed

It looks like Object Context is simply not created

**It crashes on NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext] what the f... is wrong it is simple code, I practicaly copied everything and it crashes**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>




@interface Start : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> {




}



- (void) SaveData;


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *timer;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;


- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;


@end



#import "Start.h"
#import "Datum.h"


@implementation Start

@synthesize timer;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;




- (void) SaveData {

    NSLog(@"start 1");

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSLog(@"start 2");

    Datum *datumcek = [NSEntityDescription
                                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Datum"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSLog(@"start 3");

    datumcek.snDatum = [NSDate date];



    NSLog(@"start 4");

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"No save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

}





- (void)viewDidLoad {

            [self SaveData];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled=NO;
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {


    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil)
    {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return __managedObjectContext;
}


- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Start" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}

/**
 Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
 */
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Start.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible;
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


         If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

         If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
         * Simply deleting the existing store:
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

         * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter: 
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

         Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}





@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add this to your app Delegate in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
self.viewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Also you should add all those coreDataStack methods in your app delegate.

And don't forget to import CoreData with

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

edit:
Sorry I realized that you don't use a view based application. I think you shouldn't call `[self saveData]` in `viewDidLoad`. Just add a quick button or add it in `viewWillDispear`

Comment: Why would I want it in app delegate? I am putting it all in view that gets activated after one option is selected and view is pushed to this one. And after selection another option app should save date to core data, and it gets really frustrating here.                             I just get lovely   int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);

Comment: So for some reason it won't work and I think it crashes because managed object context is hetting called before it's initalized. Just take a look at apples coredata code example.It would be extremly usefull if you tell us what the crash report says

Comment: argc int 1
argv char ** 0xbfffed28
*argv char * 0xbfffee3c
pool NSAutoreleasePool * 0x6b10e40
NSObject NSObject {...}
_token void * 0x7020028
_reserved3 void * 0x0
_reserved2 void * 0x0
_reserved void * 0x0
retVal int 0   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}

Comment: There is a good code example from apple's documentation. Just try it out and try to initialize the core data stack from the appDelegate. I don't know why but I'm sure it makes a difference.

Comment: ok I now get it it is in this lines

I have downloaded example code from ray wanderlich tutorial

' // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    FBCDMasterViewController *controller = (FBCDMasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;'

now I have customize them for my app